# Rails nested attributes custom validation with on create option is called after the record is saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, callback

Suppose I have the following models with nested attributes.
Request model:

```
class User::Request < ApplicationRecord 
  ## Associations
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

Item model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :request, class_name: 'User::Request'
  has_one :cart_item, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :cart, through: :cart_item
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cart_item, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Cart Item Model:

```
class CartItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :item
  validate :validate_no_duplicate_items, on: :create

  private

  def validate_no_duplicate_items
    return unless cart.items.exists?(item.id)
    errors.add(:error, 'Item already added to cart')
  end
end
```

And a controller that will create a request with the multi-level nested attributes.

```
def generate_checkout
  request = User::Request.new(request_params_with_nested_attribuets)
  if request.save
    render json: request, status: :created
  else
    render json: request.errors, status: :bad_request
  end
end
```

so the expected behaviour is that if it failed the validation in the cart_item model it will rollback and not create any of the models. But what I get is that the validation block is entered after the cart_item model is saved. Would appreciate any help I can get

Comment: *"what I get is that the validation block is entered after the cart_item model is saved"* -- This is the correct behaviour, so I'm not sure what your question is. What I would expect to see is that, for example: `cart_item_1` is created; `cart_item_2` is created; **`cart_item_3` fails validation**; `cart_item_1` and `cart_item_2` are deleted, as the database transaction is rolled back.

Comment: @TomLore Yes, indeed the example that you gave is what I want to happen, but what actually happens is that all models are saved and persisted in the database then the validation fails but no rollback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Active Record Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

> Transactions are protective blocks where SQL statements are only permanent if they can all succeed as one atomic action. The classic example is a transfer between two accounts where you can only have a deposit if the withdrawal succeeded and vice versa. Transactions enforce the integrity of the database and guard the data against program errors or database break-downs. So basically you should use transaction blocks whenever you have a number of statements that must be executed together or not at all.

```
def generate_checkout
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    request = User::Request.new(request_params_with_nested_attribuets)
    if request.save
      render json: request, status: :created
    else
      render json: request.errors, status: :bad_request
    end
  end
end
```